# CSS border radius and border collapse

Tags: html, border, css

I'm trying to have a table with a border-radius of 12px set in CSS. There is no border on the tr or td within the table, just the one border around the whole lot. I want the first row in the table to have a border-radius on the top 2 corners but not on the bottom 2 (so it is like a header for the table) which I have managed to do. However, this is creating a white border between the table and this first row - I want them to be right up to each other without the white border as the header row has a coloured background.

I've tried using border-collapse to do this, but this cancels out the border-radius on the overall table, making the header row rounded on the top 2 corners but inside a squared off table.

This is quite difficult to explain so an example can be found [here](http://redsquirrelsoftware.co.uk/support/test.html). You can see the white border between the table and the row with the blue background.

Has anyone got any ideas how to get rid of the border without border-collapse?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

`<table class="admin" style = "border-spacing:0px;">`

Obviously you can pull that inline style out into its own class, but I wanted to explicitly show you that border-spacing on the table is what you're after.

You should/could add some padding to the content inside the table if you don't want the text to be snug against the table's border.

Comment: Thanks! Had never heard of `border-spacing` before!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my css with fix:

```
table {
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px; //Any radius you want. It will work perfectly!
    border-spacing: 0;
}
table td:first-child, table td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child){
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
table tr:first-child td, table tr:not(:last-child) td {
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

table thead tr:first-child  td:first-child {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
}

table thead tr:first-child  td:last-child {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
}
table tbody tr:last-child  td:first-child {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}

table tbody tr:last-child  td:last-child {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}
```