# How can I get rid of the fact that every 5th row in my table has a thicker border-bottom?

Tags: css, html-table

I noticed that my table, in which i set a border-collapse:collapse and border-bottom: 1px solid grey, has a thicker line between the rows every 5th row. How can I get them to also be 1px?

I also noticed that I cannot set a border-radius. Why is that?

Here's my code:

```
.list table {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 95%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px; //HAS NO EFFECT
}

.list th, .list td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Could you share your html code also?

Comment: border-collapse and border-radiius don't mix - see further discussion on this at [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055620/css-border-radius-and-border-collapse

Comment: maybe a border-top on td is enough, but where is your HTML/CSS to demonstrate your issue ?

Comment: Sorry for late reaction. For some strange reason I could fix it by setting border to 0.5px...

Answer (score 0):

No problem with thicker `border-bottom` for me here. So your problem most likely lies within your HTML which you did not share...

```css
.list table {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 95%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px; //HAS NO EFFECT
}

.list th, .list td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
      <td>Row 1 Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
      <td>Row 2 Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 3 Data 2</td>
      <td>Row 3 Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 4 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 4 Data 2</td>
      <td>Row 4 Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 5 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 5 Data 2</td>
      <td>Row 5 Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 6 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 6 Data 2</td>
      <td>Row 6 Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 7 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 7 Data 2</td>
      <td>Row 7 Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 8 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 8 Data 2</td>
      <td>Row 8 Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 9 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 9 Data 2</td>
      <td>Row 9 Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 10 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 10 Data 2</td>
      <td>Row 10 Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 11 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 11 Data 2</td>
      <td>Row 11 Data 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for late reaction. For some strange reason I could fix it by setting border to 0.5px...